# update data from database <select><option> without submit using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i wanna ask something. how i can update data from database from  without submit.

for example :

```
<select name = 'city'>
<option value = '1' SELECTED>new york</option>
<option value = '2'>france</option>
<option value = '3'>indonesia</option>
</select>
```

if i change my select option into indonesia, my script will auto update into database set value city into '3', and indonesia will automatic be selected.

```
<select name = 'city'>
<option value = '1'>new york</option>
<option value = '2'>france</option>
<option value = '3' SELECTED>indonesia</option>
</select>
```

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to use **Ajax**, which will allow you to do server side call without refreshing the page.

on change event of dropdown you need to write the script which will update do server side processing.

e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Thanks
Amit

Comment: i already know using <select onchange="examplethis.value)"> to update select option without submit. but i didn't know how to implementation this ajax into my controller or my view using laravel 5. thank you

Comment: @HartolioWijaya you need to add your AJAX code in to view part. in view part you will call controller and its action which will in turn do database operation using model and will return response, which you will parse in ajax code again and then you can put success or failure message.

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<select name = 'city' data-url="{{url('/')}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}>
<option value = '1' SELECTED>new york</option>
<option value = '2'>france</option>
<option value = '3'>indonesia</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
  var city_id =  $( "select option:selected" ).val();
  var token = $(this).data('token');
  var base_url = $(this).data('url');
     $.ajax({
        url:base_url+'/update_city',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { _token :token,city_id:city_id },
        success:function(msg){
           alert("success");
        }
     });

})
```

Route

```
Route::post('update_city','TestController@updateCity');
```

TestController.php

```
public function updateCity(Request $request){
  $place_id = $request->get('city_id');
  // do database operations required
  return 'success';

}
```